# write multiple images to outputstream in java

Tags: java, outputstream

I have a folder called images under resources folder in eclipse.
And I have multiple images in images folder.
I want to display all the images in my browser by calling a web-service.
I have tried the following code.I am able to retrieve only one image.I want this for multiple images.How can I do this?

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("images/").getPath());

            final String[] EXTENSIONS = new String[]{
                    "png","jpg"// and other formats you need
            };
            // filter to identify images based on their extensions
            final FilenameFilter IMAGE_FILTER = new FilenameFilter() 
            {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(final File dir, final String name) {
                    for (final String ext : EXTENSIONS) {
                        if (name.endsWith("." + ext)) {
                            return (true);
                        }
                    }
                    return (false);
                }
            };
            if (file.isDirectory()) 
            {   
                 //list of files I get
                for (final File fi : file.listFiles(IMAGE_FILTER)) 
                {
                    OutputStream out =null;
                    OutputStream out1 =null;
                    BufferedImage bi =null;
                    try 
                    {
                        System.out.println("file" +fi);
                        //I get different files from images folder and add that to bufferedImage.
                        bi= ImageIO.read(fi);

                        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                        out= response.getOutputStream();
                        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", out);
                        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out);
                        out.close();
                    }
                    catch (final IOException e) 
                    {
                        // handle errors here
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: It maybe because you are closing reponse output stream in each iteration? `out.close()`. Can you move this statement to finally block outside your loop and try?

Comment: @AniketThakur I have tried that but still the same problem.

Comment: If you want this to work in a normal web browser, your approach won't work. Simply because browsers expect one image per request/response. You need to create one service/resource that creates a list of all the files (i.e an HTML response with multiple IMG tags) and then another service that will process one image at a time, that can translate the path or other identifier from the HTML into the path where the files are located on your server (most web servers already do these things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources are not files. There is no guarantee that they will even exist in a filesystem, only inside a JAR or WAR file. So using File methods isn't going to work.

In any case just serializing a stream of images to a browser isn't going to work either. You should be generating an HTML page with `<img>` elements in it, with URLs for the images, and organizing that those URLs are downloadable. Probably using the resource mechanism isn't appropriate in the first place.